# How to resize raw data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a ImageData which is Uint8ClampeArray type, and I can display it by using putImageData(img,0,0), but It displays the original length and width image which is too large.
I am wondering is there a way to resize it to fit into specified size canvas?
some related code:

```
img.src = "http://xxxxx.png";
 var c = Filters.getPixels(img);
            var imga=Filters.threshold (c, 100,90);//threshold img
            var cc = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            console.log(imga);//imga is an raw ImageData(1024*1024)
            var ctx = cc.getContext("2d");
            ctx.putImageData(imga,0,0);

/*******do something to resize ctx********/
```

Or, can drawImage() show that raw ImageData(imga)?

Any help appreciated

Comment: After painting on a canvas, just use `drawImage` to draw a resized version of it on another canvas. Your canvas will essentially be a buffer containing the image, so now you can draw it again and again.

Comment: @somethinghere drawImage(img,0,0), what the first parameter should be? imga? Could you give me some specific code to explain it more clear, Thank you so much!

Comment: Your first agument can be a `CanvasImageSource`, which is either an image node, another canvas, a video or any other node that qualifies for this. So once you draw your image data into a canvas, just use `drawImage( <canvas>, ... )` in order to resize it onto another canvas.

Comment: @somethinghere thank you so much! problem solved

Comment: Nice! Be sure to check out the docs on all things canvas, they're pretty good and explain this thing in reasonably fine detail :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: @MMzztx you should post your solution to help future visitors. Your allowed to answer your own questions on SO

Comment: @somethinghere thanks a lot!

Comment: @ProfessorAllman sure, I am going to do so

Answer (score 2):

As @somethinghere mentioned, 'use drawImage( , ... ) in order to resize it onto another canvas', in this particular case, I do:

```
var cc2 = _("myCanvasShow");
var ctx2 = cc2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.drawImage(cc,0,0,512,512);
```

which cc2 is another canvas, and resize cc into cc2.